# How to prevent babel transform operator 'typeof' in JS

Tags: babeljs

I develope a JS SDK with ES6 grammar. The file size of the SDK is about 8Kb. After compile it with babel, size of SDK is about 20Kb. I find that babel transforms operator `typeof` with a helper "**babel-runtime/helpers/typeof**", which increase my SDK's size. If I don't use `typeof` in my SDK, the file size of my SDK is about 7Kb.

```js
_validateCallback(fnName, arg) {
    if (typeof arg !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError(`[${fnName}]'s arguments[0] must be a function, but get a ${typeof arg}`);
    }
}
```

The detail of my **.babelrc**:

```js
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "ie >= 9"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime"
    ]
}
```

The `devDependencies` of **package.json**

```js
{
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.37.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
 }
```

The detail of my **webpack.config.js**

```js
{
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'botapp-sdk.' + PACKAGE.version + '.js',
        library: 'BotApp', 
        libraryTarget: 'var', 
    },
    plugins: [

        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin(PACKAGE.name + ' - ' + PACKAGE.version),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to prevent babel to transform 'typeof', so that I can reduce file size of my SDK.

Is there any way to prevent babel transform operator `typeof` ?

Comment: What is your current Babel configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have been supplement the question. @loganfsmyth

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been find a way to solve the question:

```sh
@@ -8,7 +8,10 @@
                         "last 2 versions",
                         "ie >= 9"
                     ]
-                }
+                },
+                "exclude": [
+                    "transform-es2015-typeof-symbol"
+                ]
             }
         ],
         "stage-2"
```

The detail of `exclude` see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude

Comment: In the latest version of `@babel/preset-env`, the plugin name should be `@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have no idea, what is the problem with `typeof`, as it seem to be a day one feature of ES. There is some issue with `Symbol` object, but I didn't find any article highlighting the problem.

Anyways, the possible solution is just to drop `typeof`:

```js
!(arg instanceOf Function)
```

Also, a solid workaround is an oldstyle typechecker:

```js
Object.prototype.toString.call(alert) === '[object Function]'
```

My prefered way is just to check if `call` exists:

```js
args.call && console.log('OK')
```

The benefit of `typeof` is that it works fine with undeclared variables.

In your case, it doesn't matter, because `arg` is declared as a function argument. In case it's not, you should use `try/catch` to avoid possible `ReferenceError`.