# How to solve Maximum call stack size exceeded error in vue.js while using typeof?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with typeof operator in Vue.js.Whenever I'm using typeof operator in my project (anywhere) I got this error!

[image]

I have installed the Webpack in Vue.js.
I have checked my package.json file and everything is good there.
So can you help me out from this problem?

my pacakage.json file is like this:

```
   {
  "name": "vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-cancel": "^0.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "element-ui": "^2.8.2",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.0",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vis": "^4.21.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-burger-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scroll-to": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.15.0",
    "vue-tour": "^1.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal example of the failing code? It's difficult to tell much from an error on its own.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at `typeof.js` to see if you can figure out why those two functions might be calling each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57194480